# Are those OpenAPI 3 paths ambiguous?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Are those OpenAPI 3 paths ambiguous?

```
/shops/{shopId}/pets/{petId}   
/shops/{shopId}/pets/_search
```

I want to answer **no** but, strictly reading the spec, I can't decide because they seem to fall into none of the 3 statements made by the spec:

1. Neither path is *concrete* (term used in the spec)
2. Paths don't seem to meet the *Templated paths with the same hierarchy but different templated names* criteria (that is not very clear to me): `"/shops/{}/pets/{}" != "/shops/{}/pets/_search "`
3. Paths do not look like the *ambiguous* example

Below is an excerpt of the OA3 spec (and nothing more: my question is on the first line).

**Excerpt of the OA3 spec**

The "Paths object" paragraph of the OpenAPI 3 specification (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md#paths-object) is stating (3 sentences, 3 statements):

> When matching URLs, concrete (non-templated) paths would be matched before their templated counterparts. Templated paths with the same hierarchy but different templated names MUST NOT exist as they are identical. In case of ambiguous matching, it's up to the tooling to decide which one to use.

Those 3 statements are followed by 3 examples (and that's it):

> Assuming the following paths, the concrete definition, /pets/mine,
> will be matched first if used:
>
> /pets/{petId}
> /pets/mine
>
> The following paths are considered identical and invalid:
>
> /pets/{petId}
> /pets/{name}
>
> The following may lead to ambiguous resolution:
>
> /{entity}/me
> /books/{id}

Comment: Not an answer to your question. However the URL `/shops/{shopId}/pets/_search` contains a verb `search` and that is a antipattern. The URL should then be `/shops/{shopId}/pets?action=_search`

Comment: @MohitMutha Why is that an anti-pattern? Rather, why is it ok to include a verb in a query parameter, but not in a path parameter?

Comment: In Http the verb is the Http method (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE etc.) signifying one of the CRUD operations. In the above case you want to `search` which is a form of GET. The `GET /shops/{shopId}/pets` says that I want a list of `pets` hence no need for the `search`/

Comment: @MohitMutha searching is a lot more than simply getting a list of pets: it is about getting a list of hits with scores and facets for instance. But I get your point: _search is not RESTful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of the spec is that they are not ambiguous, because one is *more* concrete than the other. The more concrete one takes precedence if the `{petId}` parameter value is set to `_search`.

Comment: If you can help us make the spec clearer, please do raise an issue or a pull request on the spec repo. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @mikeralphson for your answer: this is my reading too (for what it's worth...). Thanks also for your suggestion: I will raise an issue.

Comment: here is the link to the issue: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2564